# Override Flask-Security's /login endpoint

Tags: python, oauth, flask, flask-security

I'm working on a site where the users login via OAuth, not a password-based system.

Because of this, Flask-Security's default login page doesn't actually work for my use case, because I need the `/login` endpoint for the OAuth setup. I was able to make it so that my `/login` route wasn't being overridden by Flask-Security's by changing the `SECURITY_LOGIN_URL` setting option.

This is all working fine, the OAuth login page shows up and returns all the information needed.

The problem kicks in because I'm also trying to utilize the `@login_required` decorator.

If the user isn't logged in, instead of redirecting to my `/login` page, the `@login_required` decorator is redirecting to Flask-Security's page.

Obviously, the config endpoint doesn't help in this situation.

Is it possible to force Flask-Security to use my login route (OAuth) instead of its page?

Here's some example code that shows what I'm talking about with Flask-Security overriding defined routes:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager, request
from flask_security import (Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore,
                            UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required,
                            login_user, logout_user, current_user)
from passlib.context import CryptContext
import os


class Config:
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(basedir, 'db_repository')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

    DEBUG = True
    PORT = 8000
    HOST = "0.0.0.0"

    SECRET_KEY = "foobar123"


config = Config()


app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

app.config.from_object(config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

lm = LoginManager()

lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = "login"


roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
                       db.Column('user_id',
                                 db.Integer(),
                                 db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
                       db.Column('role_id',
                                 db.Integer(),
                                 db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
                       )


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
    provider_id = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def hash_password(self, password):
        self.hashed_password = pwd_context.encrypt(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return pwd_context.verify(password, self.hashed_password)


class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))


user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)

pwd_context = CryptContext(
    schemes=["bcrypt", "pbkdf2_sha256", "des_crypt"],
    default="bcrypt",
    all__vary_rounds=0.1
)


@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
@login_required
def index():
    """Handles calls to / and /index, return the panel"""
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/login")
def login():
    """Would include a bunch of OAuth stuff, not required for this example
    If you try going to this endpoint, you'll get the Flask-Security /login
    instead."""
    return render_template("login.html")

app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Funnily enough, I've come across a very similar problem today.
If I manage to resolve it in a way I'd consider elegant enough for an SO answer, I'll update this. In the meantime, my thoughts on strategies for approaching the problem are:

1. Subclass flask-security and overload only the `@login_required` decorator to redirect you to the right place. Probably quickest, if the redirection is the only issue you're having.
2. If you're solely using Oauth, then use an alternative decorator to replace `@login_required`. [Flask-OAuthlib](http://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a useful library for oath stuff and  the [documents show you how to protect a resource](http://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#protect-resource) using the `@oauth.require_oauth' decorator.

Flask-Stormpath is a commercial solution and I'm not familiar enough to comment on whether it covers this particular ground, so I shan't recommend it as a possible approach. However [for background reading](http://stormpath.com/blog/part-one-flask-authentication-problem) they have a useful overview of the authentication hornets nest associated with Flask.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to override the original Flask-Security's login view. Something like this:

```
my_blueprint = Blueprint('my_blueprint', __name__)

@bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@anonymous_user_required
def my_login_view():
    # Do whatever you want to do here. Try to find inspiration in the original code

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(my_blueprint)

# You will need to define User and Role classes, see Flask-Security's documentation
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)
```

And that's it. If you want to use the Flask-Security's original HTML template, you will need to override it as well (see [Flask-Security's documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/customizing.html)). There you just place your own view instead of the old one:

```
...
<form action="{{ url_for('my_blueprint.my_login') }}" method="POST" name="login_user_form">
...
```

Comment: I believe this works by registering the `/login` route before Flask-Security gets created. That is somewhat fragile, though, and may be difficult to pull off in a larger project. A better approach may be to override the LoginForm and add setup/teardown code in the validator method, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44911440/1749551).

Comment: I agree that it might not be the cleanest solution. Overriding the LoginForm sounds much better!